# Setting a hierarchy filter via script

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

In the top of the Hierarchy window of the Unity Editor there is a field for filtering the hierarchy:

[image: unity hierarchy window: filter]

My question is if you can set that filter from an editor script and how. I can barely find anything according to this on the web.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at this: http://nevzatarman.com/2015/01/10/unity-editor-scripting-filtering-hierarchy-by-tag-or-layer/

Comment: @d4RK thanks, but that's not quite what i'm looking for. i don't want to get objects using a filter, but set the filter of the inbuild unity hierarchy window

Comment: ah ok, now I got what you want.. But I'm afraid, that's not possible.. but will take a look at this anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to d4RK I found out how to do it using Reflection:

```
public const int FILTERMODE_ALL = 0;
public const int FILTERMODE_NAME = 1;
public const int FILTERMODE_TYPE = 2;

public static void SetSearchFilter(string filter, int filterMode) {

    SearchableEditorWindow[] windows = (SearchableEditorWindow[])Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll (typeof(SearchableEditorWindow));

    foreach (SearchableEditorWindow window in windows) {

        if(window.GetType().ToString() == "UnityEditor.SceneHierarchyWindow") {

            hierarchy = window;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (hierarchy == null)
        return;

    MethodInfo setSearchType = typeof(SearchableEditorWindow).GetMethod("SetSearchFilter", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);         
    object[] parameters = new object[]{filter, filterMode, false};

    setSearchType.Invoke(hierarchy, parameters);
}
```

This may not be the most elegant way, but it works like a charm and can easily be extended to apply the same filter to the SceneView.

Comment: Hello, what is the hierarchy variable ? Where do I initialize it ?

Comment: `setSearchType.Invoke(hierarchy, parameters);` give me this error: TargetParameterCountException: Number of parameters specified does not match the expected number.

Answer (score 2):

`UnityEditor.SceneModeUtility.SearchForType` seems to be a step in the right direction.

The good news is, that you can see the implementation of that method in MonoDevelop..
Taking a closer look at it tells us the methods we'd need.

```
public static void SearchForType (Type type)
{
    Object[] array = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll (typeof(SceneHierarchyWindow));
    SceneHierarchyWindow sceneHierarchyWindow = (array.Length <= 0) ? null : (array [0] as SceneHierarchyWindow);
    if (sceneHierarchyWindow)
    {
        SceneModeUtility.s_HierarchyWindow = sceneHierarchyWindow;
        if (type == null || type == typeof(GameObject))
        {
            SceneModeUtility.s_FocusType = null;
            sceneHierarchyWindow.ClearSearchFilter ();
        }
        else
        {
            SceneModeUtility.s_FocusType = type;
            if (sceneHierarchyWindow.searchMode == SearchableEditorWindow.SearchMode.Name)
            {
                sceneHierarchyWindow.searchMode = SearchableEditorWindow.SearchMode.All;
            }
            sceneHierarchyWindow.SetSearchFilter ("t:" + type.Name, sceneHierarchyWindow.searchMode, false);
            sceneHierarchyWindow.hasSearchFilterFocus = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        SceneModeUtility.s_FocusType = null;
    }
}
```

And now the bad news, due to their protection level, you can neither access the hierarchy window directly, nor can you use the `SetSearchFilter` method.

Maybe you could write an editor script, similar to the hierarchy view, where you have full control, and can do whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know MonoDevelop can actually do that. The rest can be done with a little bit of reflection.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not that fit, working with reflections ;-) But it's really awesome, that you figured it out! I think you should accept your answer, as mine is only the first step to a solution, while yours already is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

As of Unity 2018 there is an additional boolean parameter required for the [SetSearchFilter method](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/ProjectWindow/SearchableEditorWindow.cs#L209).

So change this line

`object[] parameters = new object[]{filter, filterMode, false};`

to

`object[] parameters = new object[]{filter, filterMode, false, false};`

This should resolve the `TargetParameterCountException` [Ugo Hed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5138142/ugo-hed) mentioned.